# store a numeric value from a cell as a number

Tags: string, excel, vba

I have a numeric string in A1 and i want to store it as a string so I can use it later on.
I tried this code but it gives me an error:

```
    Sub test2()
    Dim text As String
    text = Range("A1").Value.ToString

    End Sub
```

the error is "object required"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `VBA` and not `.Net` so you don't need `ToString`

Try this

```
Sub test2()
    Dim text As String
    text = Range("A1").Value

    MsgBox text
End Sub
```